# Trigger created but executing the event leads numeric or value error

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I created this trigger and it got created successfully. It's Sunday today and I tried to update a row in my emp table. But instead of raising error message different error of Numeric to value error is coming.

Code:

```
create or replace trigger no_update_tuesday     
before insert OR update on emp     
begin      
IF( to_char( sysdate, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) = 'SUNDAY' )
then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('Cannot do Updates on Sunday',10);     
end if;     
end;  
/

update emp 
set sal= sal +100
where empno = 105;
```

Error:

```
Trigger created.

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at "SQL_ZIBKJPGRSUSAKKAGGXUQKXHTO.NO_UPDATE_TUESDAY", line 3
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

The error is coming on update event.

Comment: By the way, as PL/SQL syntax terminates `if` conditions with `then`, it does not need brackets around them, so it's [`if condition then`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-1D6FD34F-F58B-4D0B-B7FC-F7C2C22377C3), not `if (condition) then`. (Pet peeve, sorry. One of many.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the official document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm),

To make it short which is the problem with your statement,

> Oracle provides the raise_application_error procedure to allow you to raise custom error numbers within your applications. You can generate errors and their associated text starting with -20000 and proceeding through -20999 (a grand total of 1,000 error numbers that you can use). Below we illustrate the use of the raise_application_error procedure.

Change your trigger accordingly, the first parameter to `raise_application_error` is the `error number` followed by the `error message` as the second parameter

```
create or replace trigger no_update_tuesday     
before insert OR update on emp     
begin      
  if( to_char( sysdate, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) = 'SUNDAY' )
  then 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Cannot do Updates on Sunday');     
  end if;     
end;  
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR syntax is wrong (you invert the error number with the message)

You should write

```
 then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(10,'Cannot do Updates on Sunday');
```